# Modifying MergedDictionaries in Window works but Modifying MergedDictionaries in Application does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamicresource

I am new to WPF. I was trying to skin my UI with light and dark color themes. So I defined two ResourceDictionaries as following:

```
<!-- Light.xaml-->
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Background">#DDDDDD</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
<!-- Dark.xaml-->
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Background">#222222</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I created a skin ResourceDictionary as following:

```
<!-- Skin.xaml-->
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Background}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally, I loaded them in App.xaml as MergedDictionaries as following:

```
<!-- App.xaml-->
<Application x:Class="Example.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Light.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skin.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

with Application code as following:

```
//App.xaml.cs

using System.Windows;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        bool dark = false;


        public void SwitchSkin()
        {
            if (dark)
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Source = new Uri("Light.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Source = new Uri("Dark.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }

            dark = !dark;
        }
    }
```

My example window code looks like:

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml-->
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
        <Button Click="SwitchSkin" Width="200" Height="24">Switch Skin</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

along with

```
//MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace Example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SwitchSkin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            App app = (App)Application.Current;
            app.SwitchSkin();
        }

    }
}
```

The switching code does run and `App.Resources["Background"]` updates however `App.Resources["BackgroundBrush"]` does not updates its color. Consequently, the background of the `Grid` is unchanged. To clarify, Grid background does not update even if I use `DynamicResource`. I just experimented and moved the skin resources and `SwitchSkin` methhod to `MainWindow`. Oops, it works there. `MainWindow.Resources["Background"]` and `MainWindow.Resources["BackgroundBrush"]` have same color. Though, `MainWindow.Resources["Background"]` is newer object, `MainWindow.Resources["BackgroundBrush"]` is same old object as verified from debugger. I interpret that as `DynamicResource` does not work as expected in the first case however it does work as expected in the second case.

My **question** is why the behaviors defer in two cases. I found numerous questions about skinning WPF apps but I was unable to meet one that could explain **this** to my understanding. Here is the modified code (which does work as expected) for shake of completeness:

```
<!-- App.xaml-->
<Application x:Class="Example.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
</Application>
```

with Application code as following:

```
//App.xaml.cs

using System.Windows;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
```

My example window code looks like:

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml-->
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Light.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skin.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
        <Button Click="SwitchSkin" Width="200" Height="24">Switch Skin</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

along with

```
//MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace Example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool dark = false;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SwitchSkin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dark)
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Source = new Uri("Light.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Source = new Uri("Dark.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }

            dark = !dark;
        }

    }
}
```

I am sorry if it reads too long. I could not make it any more compacter.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected if you replace the resource dictionaries with new ones each time you switch themes:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    bool dark = false;

    public void SwitchSkin()
    {
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

        if (!dark)
        {
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
            {
                Source = new Uri("Dark.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
            {
                Source = new Uri("Light.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
            });
        }

        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("Skin.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });

        dark = !dark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not answer my question.